# Sending JSON string using JQUERY POST returns 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

This is a very strange issue that's driving me crazy for few hours now. I want to send a JSON string to PHP using JQUERY POST.

Snippet used to posting:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.post('/test.php',
     {
           results: '{"having"}'
     },
     function(data, textStatus) {
              alert(data);
     });
});
</script>
```

I don't know why sending the word "having" as JSON string is not working. Is this a reserved word or something? The code is very simple. The "test.php" file is there. Everything seems well.

I'm getting this in the console log:

```
POST http://domain.com/test.php 403 (Forbidden)
```

Comment: Does the server require login, or some other form of authentication? Why do you believe the word `having` in the data is causing the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the value you're passing be sent via `data: '{"having"}'` rather than `results`?

Comment: that's illegal json anyways. `{}` is an object, which MUST have `{"key":"value"}` format.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no the file is actually empty. It's just a test script. I don't know but replacing the word "having" solves the problem! I realised this when testing an actual production script and finding that it stops when this word is present

Comment: Without seeing `test.php`, it's tough to say *what* might be the problem. Can you post an HTML form successfully to the same URL? If so, can you show us that form?

Comment: @MarcB I know it's wrong format. This is just a test script. The error is there when using the correct format of `{"key":"value"}` also

Comment: But you said it succeeds without the word "having" being there. Can you show the *exact* JS you use when doing that? Or, again, a working form? Or test.php? Or literally anything that might help us find the problem?

Comment: the script is simple as the one posted. That's why it's very strange!

Comment: "As simple as the one posted". But not the same, in some way we can never see. One works, one doesn't, with the top-secret PHP. Nothing you've shown could cause this problem on it's own, and you haven't shown a working version *or* the (server-side) part that might be at fault.

Comment: @PaulRoub when I say it's as simple I mean It's actually the same script. I don't know why don't you believe me!

Comment: @MichaelSamuel The working version - the version where "having" is omitted - the slight variation on the script that *might* shed some light. That version. But without the mysterious test.php, I'm still not sure how far we'll get.

Comment: @PaulRoub Man, the file with HTML is itself the test.php and It has no PHP code. That's why I'm telling you it's simple as that

Comment: well, the webserver could be refusing the connection before php ever gets involved at all. e.g. doesn't matter WHAT parameter you fire off in the `{results:...}`, it never gets seen. start debugging: do silly stuff-  setup a dinky .html file and fire a post at the script using a normal form instead of ajax.

Comment: It turned out to be a protective measure against SQL injection. So words as "SELECT" and "HAVING" in double quotes like this block the POST request from being sent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange indeed. From the given info, the below are my suggestive questions...

- Is the POST trying to access the correct URL within your application?
- Is the URL namespace role-based-security dependent?
- Does your application have any CSRF like security token that you have missed in your request?
- Is there any security-related request interceptor looking for SQL queries in the search keywords, in order to disallow SQL injection? (Because `having` is an SQL keyword, after all.)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I began to feel It has to do with word "HAVING" and SQL injection as sending the same word in double quotes like this `"having"` will still be a problem and it's known that subqueries are used in double quotes like this for SQL injection as you pointed out but I'm not really sure Is it the actual problem or not :(

Comment: Your mention of the words 'testing an actual production script' (in the comments) gave me the idea, actually. I too am not sure, if it is indeed the root cause. It was just an intelligent guess.

Comment: MAN, YOU ARE JUST A SMART*** :D I tried with other SQL words like "SELECT" and it still gets blocked! Then I tried  he same script on my other web host and It worked properly! So, It's a protection (though I consider this a stupid) measure to protect against SQL injection. The solution is to skip double quotes. However, I will ask my host to turn off this feature if possible as I use prepared statements with bind to avoid SQL inject and no need for this confusing feature

Comment: Great.. That solves the very strange issue. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try by escaping the quotes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.post('/test.php',
     {
           results: "{\"having\"}"
     },
     function(data, textStatus) {
              alert(data);
     });
});
```

Comment: which would STILL be illegal json...